# Namespace that seems it doesn't exist is working but why?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have this exercice folder that gave me instructions on how to install the web application:

So this folder contains a `.sh` file that installs the necessary things:

```
npm install
curl -o phpunit -L https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-7.phar
chmod +x phpunit
./phpunit --version
```

So basically this adds a file called `phpunit` inside root folder. So by far I kind of understand what's going on, so this installs node dependencies and also installs phpunit (I think so), but this project has a test example unit:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class HelloWorldTest extends TestCase
{
  public function testWhenGetDataFromHelloWorld(): void
  {
    $this->assertEquals('Hello World', 'Hello World');
  }
}
```

At this point is where I don't get how is `use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;` working, since I don't have any folder called PHPUnit, I get that `use` is something like importing a class, but still, how is this working (when I run the test it does not give me any kind of error)?, also, it appears that vscode detects the import as an error because it seems that it doesn't exist.

My file tree is as follows:

[image]

Can someone explain me, please?

Comment: It probably got included by composer in your vendors folder.  Read about [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) autoloading.  If you are not using composer, you should but it maybe working because your IDE includes PHPUnit.

Comment: @AlexBarker I don't have a vendor folder.

Comment: @AlexBarker Dependencies are being installed with node (inside "node_modules"), node is starting a php server, and I'm not using any IDE, I'm using just the code editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because all the dependencies are in the `phpunit-7.phar` file, which was named `phpunit` by that script.

> "The easiest way to obtain PHPUnit is to download a PHP Archive (PHAR) that has all required (as well as some optional) dependencies of PHPUnit bundled in a single file."

[PHPUnit - Installing PHPUnit - PHP Archive (PHAR)](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.3/installation.html)

Comment: Okay, I get it, so this works when running phpunit as `php phpunit [options]`